# How to compare two MySQL sql file in linux without using mysql command

Tags: mysql, shell

I have two sql file, new.sql and old.sql. New.sql may have new tables as old.sql but basically two sql data are different. What is the best way for me to compare two of them in linux if there are any new table on new.sql. Add those tables and the data from those tables into old.sql
I tried to use `diff old.sql new.sql > diff.txt` and grep the difference and it turn out I can not volid the data difference. Like following how can i just create tablek with data k1, k2 into old.sql from new.sql

old.sql

```
==========
tableA
==========
col1    col2
a1      a2

==========
tableB
==========
col1    col2
b1      b2

==========
tableC
==========
col1    col2
c1      c2
```

new.sql

```
==========
tableA
==========
col1    col2
a11      a22

==========
tableB
==========
col1    col2
x1      x2

==========
tableK
==========
col1    col2
k1      k2
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the Linux kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed` to extract just the table names from the files. Use process substitution to provide these as arguments to the `comm` command, which will show the lines from `new.sql` that aren't in `old.sql`.

```
comm -13 <(sed -n '/=======/,/=======/p old.sql | sort -u) <(sed -n '/=======/,/=======/p new.sql | sort -u)
```

Comment: thanks for the info however,i am looking for something that i can insert the extra data with new table.

Comment: Once you get the table names, you could use `mysqldump` to dump those tables from the old database, and then load that dump file into the new DB.